# Don't understand why align-items (center) don't work

Tags: html, css

Below is my CSS and HTML respectively:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: #0073d9;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this is a simple question, but I just cannot fix it.  I have put the align-items property and assigned "center" value to the body, I don't understand why the 170px by 170px square still can't be placed in center vertically.

I will be grateful if you can let me know where I get wrong.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

It is centered. Body just has the same height as the element. If you create higher body (*for example `100vh` which means 100% of viewport*) you can see it is centered.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

div {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: #0073d9;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Yes, I understand to most of people this is simple, but not me at this moment. Thanks.

Comment: Its ok. `height: 100%` can be tricky but it is 100% of the parent element and there is no parent element here.